# AWS Consolidating Billing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing

I have a question regarding linked accounts: is it possible to link an account to another account, that is already linked to a third account? For example: Holding A has a single AWS account and two daughter companies - company AA and company AB. Company AA has it's own AWS account linked to A-account and wants to have one account for each AA department linked to an AA-account. Maybe, each department wants to have some linked accounts as well. Is this architecture actually possible? Or should all lowest-level accounts be directly linked to the A-account for consolidating billing? If it is possible, are there any limits on the length of this "chain"?

Thank you.

Kind regards,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

AWS Organisations is what you are looking for https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/